# is this right syntax for ignoring .meta in any folder?

Tags: git, gitignore

```
Darians-MacBook-Pro:village-makeover darianhickman$ cat .gitignore
*.pyc
/ige
/libs
/config.yaml
/config-dev.yaml
/config-prod.yaml
/.venv
/client/deploy
/.idea
/client/index_deploy.csstest.html
**/.DS_Store
**/.meta
update_prod.sh
villagegamedev2_deploy.sh
```

Even with this ignore selector **/.meta i'm still seeing commit message below.  I have no idea why the selector **/.DS_Store works as expected but **/.meta doesn't.

```
#   (use "git push" to publish your local commits)
#
# Changes to be committed:
#       new file:   assets/audio/Music.meta
#       new file:   assets/audio/Stings_Jingles.meta
#       new file:   assets/audio/music/CGM_Bonus Level - FULL.wav.meta
#       new file:   assets/audio/music/CGM_Bonus Level - Rhythm Only.wav.meta
#       new file:   assets/audio/music/CGM_Game Lose 1 (fast).wav.meta
#       new file:   assets/audio/music/CGM_Game Lose 1.wav.meta
#       new file:   assets/audio/music/CGM_Game Lose 2.wav.meta
#       new file:   assets/audio/music/CGM_Game Lose Jingle 1_loop (fast).wav.meta
#       new file:   assets/audio/music/CGM_Game Lose Jingle 1_loop.wav.meta
#       new file:   assets/audio/music/CGM_Game Win 1 (fast).wav.meta
#       new file:   assets/audio/music/CGM_Game Win 1.wav.meta
#       new file:   assets/audio/music/CGM_Game Win 2.wav.meta
#       new file:   assets/audio/music/CGM_Game Win Jingle 1_loop (fast).wav.meta
#       new file:   assets/audio/music/CGM_Game Win Jingle 1_loop.wav.meta
#       new file:   assets/audio/music/CGM_Level 1 - FULL.wav.meta
#       new file:   assets/audio/music/CGM_Level 2 - (no per.).wav.meta
#       new file:   assets/audio/music/CGM_Level 2 - 30s (no per.).wav.meta
#       new file:   assets/audio/music/CGM_Level 2 - FULL.wav.meta
#       new file:   assets/audio/music/CGM_Level 3 - FULL.wav.meta
#       new file:   assets/audio/music/CGM_Level 3 - No Melody.wav.meta
#       new file:   assets/audio/music/CGM_Main Theme - FULL.wav.meta
#       new file:   assets/audio/music/CGM_Map - FULL.wav.meta
#       new file:   assets/audio/music/CGM_Map - Intro.wav.meta
#       new file:   assets/audio/music/CGM_Map - No Intro.wav.meta
#       new file:   assets/audio/music/CGM_Store - FULL.wav.meta
#       new file:   assets/audio/music/Casual Game Music Pack by [WOWSound].pdf.meta
```

Any suggestion what I need to change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are ignoring the file `.meta`, not `*.meta`.

You can just do this:

```
*.meta
```

That will ignore every `*.meta` file in every directory.

Likewise, `.DS_Store` should just be listed as

```
.DS_Store
```

to ignore all instances of it.

Answer (score 1):

The .gitignore file should be located at the root of your git project (alongside your .git folder).

Then, to ignore all *.meta files in any folder of you git project simply add the following to your .gitignore:

```
*.meta
```

Comment: ah. I updated it to **/*.meta and that worked. I'll try the simplest syntax soon.